# Why do we need TLSNotary in Blockchain?

Tags: ssl, blockchain, public-key-encryption

Using HTTPS, we could actually get the certificate and the public key of google.

In the case that we do not care about privacy. How about letting the smart contract to check the signature of the data sent by a website.

A simpler solution: Maybe hard code the public key of the data source into the smart contract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is reasonable, and has been invented in 2015 by [Emercoin](https://emercoin.com/) team.

[emerSSL](https://emercoin.com/files/uploads/docs/EMCSSL.pdf) already stores in the blockchain hash of user's SSL-certificate. And this system already works in production, for example, on [Livecoin](https://emercoin.com/en/news/logging-on-to-livecoinnet-with-emerssl) exhcange.